# NodeJS close/error event when computer gets killed?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have a NodeJS server set up that accepts TLS connections using the tls module: http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html

The clients are are using the NodeJS TLS module for the connections. I'm also storing a list/hashmap of all connected client and their IDs. If a client disconnects, then I will remove it from the list using the "error", "clientError" and "close" events.

This works in any normal case - however, when I "kill" the client (unplug power, unplug network cable) it seems like there is no event fired and the stream is open forever. Maybe I have overlooked something, but is there an event for something like this or how can I detect when the stream is not there any longer?

Sure, I could poll it in a certain interval, but that does not sound pretty good, since it will cause a lot of traffic (for almost no reason).

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: Looking at my log it looks ilke ~30 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the stream is actually closed. If you try to call write, then it will cause an "write after end" error. Sadly, it seems like there is no event fired when the stream itself closes.

So right now, I'm just trying to write something every few minutes to see if the stream is still alive.